# jquery tooltip not displaying from ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a list of movies and their info displayed from mysql in a table on a JSP. Each movie's table entry looks like `<a id="135006" onmouseover=ajaxFunction(this); href=SearchSingleMovieServlet?txt_movie_id=135006>The Life Aquatic</a>`.

My ajax function looks like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function ajaxFunction(obj){
var ajaxRequest;  

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        $( '#'+ obj.id ).tooltip({
             content: "<strong>Hi!</strong>",
             track:true
         });

         document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '#' + obj.id+ ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
var parameter = "movie_id=" + obj.id;
ajaxRequest.open("POST","MoviePopUpWindowServlet", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type"
        , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 
ajaxRequest.send(parameter);
}


</script>
```

The line `document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '#' + obj.id+ ajaxRequest.responseText;` is just a debugging line so I can see if the code enters the AJAX function and to make sure responseText displays correctly (which it does). But when I try mousing over the link of the movie, its tooltip doesn't show. Any reason why?

Comment: Do you see it second time you hover?

Comment: @SandeepNayak nope.

Comment: You need to instantiate all tooltip's once

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnfe6gsh/1/) I have put a `setTimout` to simulate `ajax` call

Comment: so does the instantiation happen inside the ajax function (inside the ready state if statement) or outside? @SandeepNayak

Comment: Both place. Else it would not work the first time

Comment: @SandeepNayak sorry, im a bit confused. So i put $("#tippy").tooltip({
    content: '... waiting on ajax ...',
    track:true
    
    
}) in the if statement, and the rest OUTSIDE the if statement?